# subdifferential rule proof

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

How to prove that the subdifferential of $f(x) = \max_{i=1,\dots, n} f_i(x)$ satisfies
        \begin{align}
        \partial f(x) = \operatorname{conv}\left( \bigcup \partial f_i(x)  \right)
    \end{align}

How am I suppose to utilize the property of convex hull here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, you'll need the Danskin-Bertsekas theorem for subdifferentials for this one. Viz,

> ***Theorem (Danskin-Bertseka's Theorem for subdifferentials).***
> *Let $Y$ be a topological vector space and $C$ be a nonempty compact subset of
> $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\phi: \mathbb R^n \times Y \rightarrow (-\infty,
> +\infty]$ be a function such that for every $x \in C$, the mapping $\Phi(x, \cdot) :
>   Y \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ is a
> closed  proper convex function. Consider the function $f:
> Y \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ defined by*
> $f(y) := \underset{x \in C}{\text{sup }}\Phi(x, y).$
> *If $f$ is proper, then it is a closed and convex. Furthermore, if $\operatorname{dom}(f)^\circ \ne \emptyset$ and $\Phi$ is
> continuous on $\mathbb R^n \times \operatorname{dom}(f)^\circ$, then for every $y \in \operatorname{dom}(f)^\circ$, we have*
> $$
> \partial f(y) = \text{conv}\{\partial_y \Phi(x, y) \mid x \in C_y\},
> $$
> *where $C_y := C \cap \operatorname{opt}(\Phi(\cdot,y)) := \{x \in C \mid \Phi(x, y) = f(y)\}$.*

Using the above theorem, one can easily establish the following lemma (which also solves your problem).

> ***Lemma (subdifferential of pointwise max of $n$ functions).***
> *Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n: Y \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ be convex functions.
> Then for every $y \in \cap_{i=1}^n \operatorname{dom}(f_i)$ such that each $f_i$ is continuous at $y$, one has the identity*
> $$
> \partial \max(f_1,\ldots,f_n)(y) = \operatorname{conv}(\cup_{i=1}^n \partial f_i(y)).
> $$

*Proof.* Let $f := \max(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. Define $\Phi:\mathbb R^n \times Y \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$
by $\Phi(x,y):=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i f_i(y)$ and note that $f(y) = \sup_{x \in \Delta_n}\Phi(x, y)$ for every $y \in Y$.
Also note that $\partial_y \Phi(x, y) = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\partial f_i(y)$ (Minkowski sum of sets). Now invoke the above theorem. $\Box$

Comment: Can anyone take a look at here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4080127 and help?