# An extension of subgradients method for nonsmooth convex optimization

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, subgradient

Please excuse my ignorance on this question. Let us consider an extension of the problem here:

[subdifferential rule proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1942634)

Suppose that $$f(x) = \max_{y\in Y} h(x, y)$$
where $Y$ is a compact set, and the functions $x \mapsto h(x,y)$ are continuous and convex for all $y \in Y.$

I am interested in the prove below but I hardly could prove this: $$\partial f(x) = \text{conv}\Big\{\bigcup \ \partial_x h(x,y) \ \Big| \ y \in Y \Big\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The result you ask about is an extension of Danskin's theorem. It is indeed true and was proved by Bertsekas in the appendix of his PhD [thesis](http://hdl.handle.net/1721.1/13795).